# Partition content from lines in text file

Tags: python, partitioning

I have some data in a text file, which is mostly paths of folders

```
home/user/Desktop/arandomname/2017/01
home/user/Desktop/couldbeanothername/2017/01
home/user/Desktop/guesswhatname/2017/01
```

I want to select the string between "Desktop/" and "/2017", I tried using position but definitely won't work since the strings are different in length

Currently I'm using

```
for i in content:
    print i.partition('/')[-1].rpartition('/20')[0]
```

The output is up to

```
home/user/Desktop/arandomname
home/user/Desktop/couldbeanothername
home/user/Desktop/guesswhatname
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: could you mark correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use split()

```
needed_data = content.split("/")[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a regular expression:

```
s = 'home/user/Desktop/arandomname/2017/01'
re.findall("Desktop/([^/]+)/\d{4}", s)[0]
# 'arandomname'
```

Or direct search:

```
m = s[s.index('Desktop/') + len('Desktop/') : ]
m[ : m.index('/')]
# 'arandomname'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

content = [
    'home/user/Desktop/arandomname/2017/01',
    'home/user/Desktop/couldbeanothername/2017/01',
    'home/user/Desktop/guesswhatname/2017/01']

for strg in content:
    path = Path(strg)
    print(path.parts[3])

# prints:
# arandomname
# couldbeanothername
# guesswhatnam
```

[`path.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) returns a tuple of the directories (and the file) that make up the path.

the module provides more path-related methods in case you need them.

Comment: @gilgameshbk you are welcome! then please accept (and upvote?) the answer. thanks.

Comment: says I have less than 15 of reputation, won't show, sorry

Answer (score -1):

Use `re` module

```
In [88]: re.match(r'.*Desktop/(.*)/2017.*', "home/user/Desktop/arandomname/2017/01").group(1)
Out[88]: 'arandomname'
```

Comment: Clearly not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: before downvoting please check the edits in question.